# How to specify custom gate set for the optimization in pytket?

Tags: compiling, pytket

I have a specific basis gate set for my system, is it possible to use pytket's predefined optimization sequences and ask it to give a final circuit using my specific gate set?

Comment: Hi modibrah, I'd be happy to answer your question. I assume by pre-defined sequences you mean passes like `FullPeepholeOptimise` or the `default_compilation_pass` for a specific `Backend`?

Comment: @Callum Yes, exactly! Thank you

Comment: Does my answer below address your question properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get pytket to give you a circuit in the desired gateset.

### The simple case

In certain cases this can be done automatically with the [auto_rebase_pass](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/passes.html#pytket.passes.auto_rebase.auto_rebase_pass). This auto rebase depends on a known set of hardcoded gate decompositions specified [here](https://github.com/CQCL/tket/blob/develop/pytket/pytket/passes/_decompositions.py). If no suitable decomposition is found for your target gateset then you will need to define you rebase manually with [RebaseCustom](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/passes.html#pytket.passes.RebaseCustom).

Typically if your gateset is one used by a hardware provider (i.e. IBM's {X, SX, CX, Rz} gateset) Then `auto_rebase_pass` will work.

```python
from pytket import Circuit, OpType
from pytket.passes import auto_rebase_pass

circ1 = Circuit(2).H(0).Rx(0.25, 1).CZ(0, 1) # test circuit

ibm_gateset = {OpType.X, OpType.SX, OpType.CX, OpType.Rz} # Target gateset

ibm_rebase = auto_rebase_pass(ibm_gateset) # Define rebase

ibm_rebase.apply(circ1) # Apply rebase pass
```

### More involved case with `RebaseCustom`

Works for any gateset for which suitable replacements are given.

Below is an example of a custom rebase taken from the [user manual](https://tket.quantinuum.com/user-manual/manual_compiler.html#rebases). Note that in addition to the target gateset I need to provide replacements to convert the gates in my circuit to  TKET's internal gateset {TK1, CX}. {TK1, TK2} is also allowed. See the [gate definitions](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/optype.html).

```python
from pytket import Circuit, OpType
from pytket.passes import RebaseCustom
from pytket.circuit.display import render_circuit_jupyter

# Target gateset
gates = {OpType.Rz, OpType.Ry, OpType.CY, OpType.ZZPhase} 

# Implement CX in terms of CY, Rz
cx_in_cy = Circuit(2)
cx_in_cy.Rz(0.5, 1).CY(0, 1).Rz(-0.5, 1) 

# Define function to implement TK1 gate in terms of Rz and Ry
def tk1_to_rzry(a, b, c): 
    circ = Circuit(1)
    circ.Rz(c + 0.5, 0).Ry(b, 0).Rz(a - 0.5, 0)
    return circ

# Define rebase
custom_rebase = RebaseCustom(gates, cx_in_cy, tk1_to_rzry)

circ2 = Circuit(3) # Test circuit
circ2.X(0).CX(0, 1).Ry(0.2, 1)
circ2.add_gate(OpType.ZZPhase, -0.83, [2, 1]).Rx(0.6, 2)

custom_rebase.apply(circ2) # apply custom transformation

render_circuit_jupyter(circ2)
```

### Combining passes

If you want to perform the gate conversion after you've applied some optimisations then you can include your rebase at the end of a `SequencePass` and the different circuit transformations will be performed in order.

```python
from pytket.passes import SequencePass, FullPeepholeOptimise

circ3 = Circuit(2).H(0).Rx(0.25, 1).CZ(0, 1).CX(1, 0).CY(0, 1)

seq_pass = SequencePass([FullPeepholeOptimise(), ibm_rebase])

# Apply FullPeepholeOptimise followed by gateset rebase
seq_pass.apply(circ)
```

I hope this helps. We hope to have a more intuitive interface for gate conversion in future releases.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question perfectly! I will start working on a base code and come back to this thread if I faced any problems!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Also, I'm following the steps here [link](https://cqcl.github.io/pytket/manual/manual_circuit.html#custom-parameterised-gates) to create a custom gate (Rxy). Once I define the gate, how do I include it in the set `gates = {OpType.Rz, OpType.CZ, etc}`?

Comment: The solution was to define my gate as shown in the documentation, and use `OpType.CustomGate` in the gates list

Comment: Yes this should work :) Let me know if there are further issues

Comment: I have two issues:

1.  How can I specify more "accurate decompositions for my gate set beyond [TK1, CX]<-> [basis - gates]? For example, one of my base gates is Rxy. TK1 can be implemented using two Rxy gates. However, gates such as Rx or Ry can be implemented using a single Rxy gate, how can I tell this to pytket? If I don't do so, it will do Rx -> TK1 -> Rxy Rxy, instead of Rx -> Rxy

2. When creating a pass sequence, I would prefer for the `RebaseCustom` pass to run before other passes. But I sometimes get the error `RuntimeError: Cannot obtain matrix from op: CustomGate` when I do so.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue. If this still is causing problems maybe we could discuss this further in the tket slack channel? You can find the link in the README of the pytket github repository.

Comment: Or alternatively you could make a separate stack exchange post if you would prefer